# How can I change the logo (not the site image) at the top of my SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint

I have recently been assigned as a SharePoint Administrator and while I have managed to figure many things out on my own, I seem to be stumped with how to change the logo/text located near the top of the page.

I'm not referring to the site image, which is easy to change.

I have SharePoint Designer and have mucked my way through various master pages and css files only to end up more confused than when I started.  Can anyone, anywhere help me out here?  I can't figure out which file and what lines need to be modified to change the logo.  Thank you tons.

While I'm a new user and not allowed to upload photos to my posting, I took a screenshot of what I'm trying to change (the logo above the Training menu) and it can be found at the following URL.

http://tinypic.com/r/15xl2t5/7

Thanks again!

Comment: Marek, I updated the original question with a link to a screenshot of what I'm trying to change.  I tried to upload the screenshot here but since I'm not registered and new it wouldn't let me.  Thanks!

Comment: @Marek, while I believe that would work if we weren't using custom master pages and css files, what I'm trying to figure out is where in the master pages or css files is this value being set as it seems to override any changes I make to the area you've described.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it using SharePoint Designer, but here's how you can do it in a browser:

1. navigate to the **Title, Description, and Icon** page (`Site Actions` > `Site Settings` > `Title, description, and icon`),
2. enter address of the logo in the **URL** field.

[image]